# Nested tables must have collapsed borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have Googled and read a few articles on SO. Unfortunately explicitly setting borders on nested tables is not an option - I am positive I have done this before using `border-collapse: collapse`

Maybe I imagined the whole thing. I have the following CSS:

```
    .table-grid {
        width: 100%;

    }

    .table-grid > thead > tr > th, 
    .table-grid > tbody > tr > th, 
    .table-grid > tfoot > tr > th, 
    .table-grid > thead > tr > td, 
    .table-grid > tbody > tr > td, 
    .table-grid > tfoot > tr > td {
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

Red borders still doubling up, tripling up, etc...what am I missing? Or misunderstanding?

This is for the UI of rather complicated scheduling tool for CNC machines - so DIV's are not required - I need it done using tables.

Anyway ideas?

EDIT | Markup below

```
<table class="table-grid" style="background-color: #fff">
    <tr>
        <th>Month
            <table class="table-grid">
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <th>Apr</th>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
```

This is somewhat trivialized - otherwise id' just keep the the Month as a colspan"7" - the actual scope is far more complicated - so colspan techniques won't suffice

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse` is a property of the *table*, not the cells. Try `.table-grid { border-collapse: collapse; }` - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f88xxw8/) to demonstrate.

Comment: I tried that too - same same

Comment: Then you'll have to include your HTML markup. As demonstrated by this basic fiddle, there is no reason it shouldn't work given the details of your question: https://jsfiddle.net/6f88xxw8/1/

Comment: Nested tables...so child tables borders merge with their parent containers and so on. Figuring out border-left, etc for every child is not feasible due to the arbitrary nature of the nesting, etc.

Comment: `border-collapse` affects *cell borders*. It cannot merge borders of two completely independent elements (like nested tables). You'll need to get creative with the borders of the child table. I'll create an example.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/6f88xxw8/6/ - I've resolved a few errors in your markup as well (outer table isn't closed, inner-table is missing `<tr>`).

Comment: I'll be honest - my CSS skills are not the sharpest so pardon me if I misunderstood - but will this accommodate an arbitrary number of deptch of nested tables? The example I gave was trivial - there could be ten levels of nested tables - will this still work without changing the CSS? Thats ultimately what I need. CSS that would work with any depth of table nesting...

Comment: Yes, this should work with any level. Example [can be seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/6f88xxw8/7/).

Comment: Holy carp...thats complicated CSS I would not have figured that out on my own - thank you - appears to work on multiple nest levels. The .table-grid .table-grid had me thinking it was fixed to two levels. :) Quick question...how do I add padding to cells now without buggering the borders alignments? Haha

Comment: At this point I am using line-height - which seems to work assuming these cells only ever have basic text...any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmmmm... that's an interesting one. Let me think.

Comment: I'm going to submit my previous solution as an answer, as I feel it adequately solves the original question. I'm not sure if the padding portion is actually possible but I'll keep thinking.

Comment: Giver it seems to work so far I am happy with what I am seeing - I accept your answer :) Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`border-collapse: collapse;` must be applied to the *table* for it to take effect, rather than the table cells. However, `border-collapse` only works on table cells (`<td>` or `<th>`) that share a common parent `<table>`. This means that you cannot merge cells of nested tables, nor can you merge elements that aren't `<td>` or `<th>` elements.

In your example this becomes a bit tricky being that all tables, including the nested ones, share the same single class.

With a little creative CSS, we can hide the bottom and left borders from all our nested cells. Additionally, we'll have to remove the *right* border of the last cell in a row.

Using a combination of the nested selector `.table-grid .table-grid`, as well as `:last-child` for altering the final cell of a nested row, you can come up with an infinitely "nestable" example that looks something like this:

```css
.table-grid {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-grid>tbody>tr>th {
  padding: 0;
}

.table-grid>thead>tr>th,
.table-grid>tbody>tr>th,
.table-grid>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-grid>thead>tr>td,
.table-grid>tbody>tr>td,
.table-grid>tfoot>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.table-grid .table-grid td,
.table-grid .table-grid th {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}

.table-grid .table-grid td:last-child,
.table-grid .table-grid th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-grid" style="background-color: #fff">
  <tr>
    <th>Month
      <table class="table-grid">
        <tr>
          <th>Jan</th>
          <th>Feb</th>
          <th>Mar</th>
          <th>Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you also can do is add this styling to the child table

```
width: calc(100% + 2px);
border-collapse: collapse;
border: none;
margin-left: -1px;
```